# Out of bounds exception in getSubimage() method

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have made a small piece of code to split spritesheets into seperate images...

```
private BufferedImage sheet, dirt, grass, rock, tree, water;

    int width = 64, height = 64;

        public void split() {
            dirt = sheet.getSubimage(0,0,width,height);
            grass = sheet.getSubimage(width,0,width*2,height);
            rock = sheet.getSubimage(width*2,0,width*3,height);
            tree = sheet.getSubimage(0,height,width,height*2);
            water = sheet.getSubimage(width,height,width*2,height*2);
        }
```

Now, the first two (dirt and grass) go well as expected. However, the issue is with the rock cropping line. For some reason it drops an exception...

"
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside of Raster
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:1245)

"

So apparently the issue is to do with the x value being "out of bounds". But the x value is (width * 2), so 128pix, which is well in bounds of this image (192x128), which I've attached as proof.

I've also changed the code a little to crop with the x value being 1 for rock but I still get the issue, same with using the same dimensions for anothe bufferedImage.

Sorry for anything wrong in this post, it's my first time.

Thanks in advance

[The image](http://s15.postimg.org/ejcjvcyez/Tilesheet_fw.png)

Comment: So 128 is in the Java range 0-128?

Comment: I've never done this, but I don't think you are thinking of it correctly in terms of height and width. By the way the docs say, x and y are the upper left corner, which you have, but after that I would think normal width and height would be appropriate here. Since you are STARTING at a certain point, you dont have to compensate for the width or height, which is where I think you are going wrong. Try doing, for width and height (not x and y) just `width, height` and the reason `grass` doesn't give you an error is because you have a third option `rock` next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering off my comment.

So you are on the right path, but not quite understanding how `getSubimage()` works.

The docs say

> Parameters:
>
> x - the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular region
>
> y - the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular  region
>
> w - the width of the specified rectangular region
>
> h - the height of the specified rectangular region

You are correctly setting you `x` and `y` values, however you are mistaken in setting you `width` and `height` values.

Since you are starting at point `(x,y)` you do not need to compensate for the `width` and the `height` like you are, instead just use them as they are.

So, you code would be

```
public void split() {
            dirt = sheet.getSubimage(0,0,width,height);
            grass = sheet.getSubimage(width,0,width,height);
            rock = sheet.getSubimage(width*2,0,width,height);
            tree = sheet.getSubimage(0,height,width,height);
            water = sheet.getSubimage(width,height,width,height);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks man! WOW I can't believe I missed something so simple XD